# Android: CollapsingToolbarLayout and SwipeRefreshLayout get stuck

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I use CollapsingToolbarLayout, RecyclerView and SwipeRefreshLayout together:

**Xml:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/collapse_toolbar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <include
            layout="@layout/activity_main_toolbar"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <cz.yetanotherview.webcamviewer.app.helper.EmptyRecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/mainList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floating_action_button"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_edit"
        android:onClick="assignSelectedWebCamsToCategory"/>

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
        android:id="@+id/floating_action_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        fab:menu_shadowColor="#37000000"
        fab:menu_colorNormal="#DA4336"
        fab:menu_colorPressed="#E75043"
        fab:menu_colorRipple="#99FFFFFF"
        fab:menu_icon="@drawable/fab_add"
        fab:menu_buttonSpacing="10dp"
        fab:menu_labels_textColor="@color/very_dark_grey"
        fab:menu_labels_textSize="14sp"
        fab:menu_labels_colorNormal="@color/white"
        fab:menu_labels_colorPressed="@color/next_grey"
        fab:menu_labels_colorRipple="#99FFFFFF"
        fab:menu_labels_margin="8dp"
        fab:menu_backgroundColor="@color/black_transparent">

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_content_import"
            fab:fab_size="mini"
            fab:fab_label="@string/pref_import_from_server"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white"
            app:fab_colorPressed="@color/next_grey"
            app:fab_colorRipple="#99FFFFFF"
            android:onClick="showSelectionDialog"/>

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_content_manually"
            fab:fab_size="mini"
            fab:fab_label="@string/create_manually"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white"
            app:fab_colorPressed="@color/next_grey"
            app:fab_colorRipple="#99FFFFFF"
            android:onClick="showAddDialog"/>

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_content_suggestion"
            fab:fab_size="mini"
            fab:fab_label="@string/submit_suggestion"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white"
            app:fab_colorPressed="@color/next_grey"
            app:fab_colorRipple="#99FFFFFF"
            android:onClick="showSuggestionDialog"/>

    </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<include
    layout="@layout/activity_main_drawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Code:**

```
    swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
```

How to allow swipe refresh action **only** when collapsing toolbar layout is **fully expanded** and scrollview (recyclerview) **on top**? The similar behavior like in Google+ or Inbox application.

**Wrong:**

[image]

**Good:**

[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Finally,

I found that SwipeRefreshLayout works **without any "hacks"** from Support Library version **23.1.1**.

Simply use in your layout:

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

and in code:

```
SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.green, R.color.red, R.color.yellow);
swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
       //Your refresh code here
    }
});
```

And don't forget to use:

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
```

after using your code logic ;)

Comment: With the new Support Library 23.2.0 is the problem again: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201775

Comment: 23.2 Workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35641630/recyclerviews-and-swiperefreshlayout-using-support-library-23-2-0/35643170#35643170

Comment: What if the SwipeRefreshLayout is not directly inside the CoordinatorLayout? I've a ViewPager with fragments in it using the SwipeRefreshLayout

Comment: Ok, with the Support Library 23.3.0 is again everything fine and working well ;)

Comment: For anybody struggling with this, I just wanted to point out that the `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` HAS be on the `SwipeRefreshLayout`.   I had this on my scrollable view, not the `SwipeRefreshLayout` and nothing was working.

Comment: Also for case nested RecyclerView, check here stackoverflow.com/a/36895607/1221256 – user1221256

Answer (score 116):

**Update:** This issue has been resolved in the latest version of the support library (23.1.1+). If you are using an older version of the support library either upgrade or continue reading.

If you're using an older version of the support library, add an offset change listener to your AppBarLayout to enable or disable your swipe to refresh layout accordingly. Additional code available here:

https://gist.github.com/blackcj/001a90c7775765ad5212

Relevant changes:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener {
    ...

    private AppBarLayout appBarLayout;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ...
        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.contentView);
        appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appBarLayout);

    }

    @Override
    public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int i) {
        //The Refresh must be only active when the offset is zero :
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(i == 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        appBarLayout.removeOnOffsetChangedListener(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the `SwipeRefreshLayout` was inside a `Fragment` which would be inside a `ViewPager`?

Comment: @AndyRoid I've updated my design support example on GitHub to include code for this. You need to override dispatchTouchEvent for the `Activity` in addition to listening for onOffsetChanged. Then include a public function in the `Fragment` to enable / disable the `SwipeRefreshLayout`. Full code available here: https://github.com/blackcj/DesignSupportExample

Comment: Nice job blackcj I'll check it out and see if it all looks ok! Edit: Looks clear so far based on the example I saw in your Repo, haven't tested it on a device yet. Will keep you posted.

Comment: This thing you have implemented better be in android itself.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work properly with support library v23.0.0 and v23.0.1 as the nested scrolling functionality ignores the enabled state if the nested scrolling already started. If you scroll down and up in one motion, it will trigger the refresh anyways and the AppBarLayout stays collapsed.

Comment: This is a good idea but need some fix. If it starts full expanded (SwipeRefresh enabled) and I touch beggining scroll, it'll keep enabled until I release the touch. So if I scroll down a little and scroll up again, it'll try to refresh before full expanded.

Comment: Hey, I've created an RxObservable for observing AppBarLayout state (visibility), feel free to use:
https://gist.github.com/scana/a5c0abc452abf202c9cf

Comment: I am stuck with the `SwipeRefreshLayout` was inside a `Fragment` of `MainFragment`. What can i do if i have fragments like **`ViewPager => Fragment =>Three Sub Fragment => SwipeRefreshLayout`** and have problem to scroll. Is there any solution?

Comment: In my case I have the recyclerview inside a cardview, and when I swipe upward / downward it doesn't collapse / expand the toolbar, I use support library 23.2.1 and I added app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" to the recyclerview but in vain, I added it to the cardview but in vain, I added it to both but still in vain, why the movements is not sent to the CollapsingToolbarLayout? Note, I'm using CoordinatorLayout for my activity.

Comment: @blackcj knowing that at runtime I set my recyclerview to horizonal.

Comment: You don't want to disable it if it is in the refreshing process. So I did this:
if(!this.isRefreshing()){
      this.setEnabled(i == 0);
    }

Comment: I was having an issue with this where a half swipe disabled the swipe permanently.  To fix I just changed `i == 0` to `i <= 0`.  i.e. `mSwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(i <= 0);`.

Answer (score 15):

If I understand you correctly, you want to start refreshing only after toolbar is expanded, right? So first CollapsingToolbarLayout needs to be opened and then start refreshing. I managed it by the following code:

```
     <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                      <!--PUT HERE WHAT EVER YOU WANT TO COLLAPSE, A TOOLBAR, ETC...-->
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
     <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And then, in your fragment/activity make it implement AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener (Now the refreshing is enabled when toolbar is fully expanded):

```
    @Override
    public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
        if (collapsingToolbarLayout.getHeight() + verticalOffset < 2 * ViewCompat.getMinimumHeight(collapsingToolbarLayout)) {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
```

Override onPause() & onResume() as in @blackcj answer:

```
  @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        appBarLayout.removeOnOffsetChangedListener(this);
    }
```

Then set LinearLayoutManager to your recyclerView:

```
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

For me this worked as a charm, first appBarlayout gets expanded and only then swipeRefreshLayout triggers refreshing.

Comment: need to do its with a fragment added to a nestedscrollview. I am having a hard time.

Comment: @user1232726 Hm.. and what's the problem? If you put FrameLayout inside a NestedScrollView and then from your code begin transaction to put your fragment into the framelayout it should work, no?

Comment: Hi I try to put framelayout inside nestedScrollview and try replace it with fragment contain swiperefreshlayout and recycleView inside but does not work, recycleView does not show. (remove swipeRefreshlayout, recycleview show normally)

Comment: @LêKhánhVinh, try to put android:fillViewport="true" to the nestedScrollView

Comment: recyclerView is a nestedScrollView... you do not need both.

Answer (score 1):

I had to make the RecyclerView the main child of the SwipeRefreshLayout in order to remove the issue using Support Library 23.2.0. Could not fixed it having an **include layout** inside of the SwipeRefreshLayout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/my_swipeRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!--<include layout="@layout/my_RecyclerView_layout"/> issue for me here -->

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked with offsetChangedListener for me, just a little better-performing kotlin onOffsetChanged() implementation

```
val toEnable = verticalOffset == 0
if (!swipeRefresh.isEnabled.xor(toEnable)) return
swipeRefresh.isEnabled = toEnable
```

Answer (score -2):

The **[Above Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33776549/1318946)** is Perfect for `AppCompatActivity` but If you are used `Fragment` then following snippet will help you.

Just put `NestedScrollView` in xml of `fragment`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <!-- A RecyclerView with some commonly used attributes -->
        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/album_timeline_swipe_refresh_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/album_timeline_recyclerview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clickable="true" />
        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```