# How to achieve this layout effect using colapsing toolbar layout

Tags: java, android, layout

I want  collapsing toolbar layout look like this it is visible like this default.

[image: Default Look Like this]

On Scroll up the height of `ImageView` reduces and it look like this:

[image: On scrolled Image]

After reducing the height of `ImageView`  30% to 40% the whole layout will scroll  with the reduced `ImageView`.The reduce `ImageView` must be scroll not shrink.

I need some starting point I really stuck on this.

In whole scenario toolbar remains on its position nothing happen with toolbar.

Comment: Have you tried `android:minHeight="some dp"` attribute for your `ImageView` inside `CollapsingToolbarLayout` ?

Comment: yes then it will stick on top

Comment: Try taking your `ImageView` inside any container with `ScrollView` as parent with above approach.

Comment: I need viewpager  reduces the height 30% then 
the layout  scrolls with imageview also

Comment: @JeelVankhede I want to use colapsing toolbar layout I achive this with nestedscrolview but then tabview viewpager not scroll smoothly
best solution I think is that to implement my ownoffsetchangedlistner 
but I am stuck how to use

Comment: I think that's not possible unless you try to make your custom view. please share layout xml code, will check if anything possible with it.

Comment: I fork diffrent collapsingtoolbar layout examples and try to change them
but all of them i change according to mysituation
but it stick the header on top of screen

https://github.com/hanscappelle/CoordinatorBehaviorExample/tree/master/app/src/main/java/saulmm/myapplication

Comment: @JeelVankhede xml I am currently acheiving this   with nested scrolview and on scroll i animate imageview to reduce its height
Then it will scroll normally
But using this approach 
tabview viewpagers recyclerview not work smootly

Answer (score 1):

This is the working solution I was able to come up with.

`onCreate` class:

```
    val displayMetrics = baseContext.resources.displayMetrics
    //setting the "zoomed in" effect on the image
    image.layoutParams.width = displayMetrics.widthPixels + displayMetrics.widthPixels / 2
    val originalWidth = image.layoutParams.width
    scroll_view.setOnScrollChangeListener { _: NestedScrollView?, _: Int, y: Int, _: Int, _: Int ->
        //adjust "if" check and formula as you wish
        if (y < 200) {
            image.layoutParams.width = (originalWidth - y*1.5).toInt()
            image.requestLayout()
        }
    }
```

Some clarifications. I change the image's width based on the size of the screen, so that the image is "zoomed in" at first, and then it zooms out to it's original form, as the user scrolls down.

Also make sure you have `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);` on the RecyclerView you wish to scroll smoothly.

The result if the following:

[image]

Comment: Nestedscroling enabled false means recyclerview purpose  is not fulfilled

Comment: And I am finding a solution with collapsing layout because nested scrolview with viewpager not work smoothly and many other issues I am facing with nested scrolview and viewpager

Comment: Well from your question I don't really see the point of the collapsing layout, but yea, this is just the shrinking of the image part of your question.

Comment: Yes it is answer to my question  but I will post my solution if I achieve some results

Comment: Can I achieve the same effect on  offsetchamgelistner

Comment: You could look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31872653/how-can-i-determine-that-collapsingtoolbar-is-collapsed
and inside place the same logic I placed in the scroll listener.