# Android Design Library: SwipeRefreshLayout don't detect swipe over CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, swiperefreshlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

In my app I am using `CollapsingToolbarLayout` following `NestedScrollView` inside `SwipeRefreshLayout`. What I want from `SwipeRefreshLayout` is to detect swipe over from `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, but its detecting over from `NestedScrollView` and ignoring swipe on `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/swipe"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="256dp"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

                <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:expandedTitleMarginStart="@dimen/expanded_toolbar_title_margin_start"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/profilePic"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_split_big_profile"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                        app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
                        layout="@layout/toolbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

                </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:id="@+id/transactions_scroll"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="500dp">
                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/add_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin_bottom"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
                android:onClick="addTxn"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_add_transaction_light"
                app:elevation="6dp"
                app:fabSize="normal" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Has anybody used this sort of thing?

Answer (score 5):

As stated in [AppBarLayout docs](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html), it has to be direct child of CoordinatorLayout

> This view depends heavily on being used as a direct child within a
>   CoordinatorLayout. If you use AppBarLayout within a different
>   ViewGroup, most of it's functionality will not work.

Thus, I'm not sure where the SwipeToRefreshLayout has to be included to work together with the CollapsingToolbar, as NestedScrollView has to be direct child too.

Here is [another response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30785823/5264983) that helps to attach the SwipeRefreshLayout and activate it only when the appBar is uncollapsed, but they are not using a NestedScrollView, which doesn't work for me :(

---

**EDIT** I found a solution for my problem: The ListView I used, had to be set as nested scroll instead of put it inside a NestedScrollView, or replaced with RecycleView:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
     listView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
}
```

So, a solution for your issue should be to wrap the NestedScrollView inside the SwipeRefreshLayout.