# Android :CollapsingToolbar is hidden after scrolling down

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

My layout includes Collapsing Toolbar and Tablayout with ViewPager If I scroll down  and the scroll back up, CollapsingToolbar gets hidden .I have to drag the tablayout or swiperefresh down to make the CollapsingToolbar visible.The toolbar should be visible after I scroll up. Please Help.
Here is my layout:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"


    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/dashboard_app_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:stateListAnimator="@null"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

                <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:contentScrim="@color/light_red"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/relative_banner"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                            android:id="@+id/dashboard_img_banner_view_pager"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="180dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                        <me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator
                            android:id="@+id/dashboard_circular_indicator_one"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/dashboard_img_banner_view_pager"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:background="@color/red_color"
                        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/rl_city_choice"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:clickable="true">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/toolbar_img"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                                android:src="@drawable/location" />

                            <org.offer_katta_ok.utils.CustomView.CustomRegularTextView
                                android:id="@+id/txt_city_name"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                                android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/toolbar_img"
                                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/toolbar_img"
                                android:text="@string/city"
                                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

                </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:behavior_overlapTop="0dp"
                app:layout_anchor="@+id/dashboard_app_bar"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/uncheck_radio_grey" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    app:behavior_overlapTop="0dp"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="none"
                    app:tabGravity="fill"
                    app:tabMode="fixed"
                    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/tab_text_color"
                    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyTabLayoutTextAppearance"
                    app:tabTextColor="@color/text_sub_content_color" />

                <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                    android:id="@+id/refresh"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tab_layout">

                    <org.offer_katta_ok.home.pagerAdapter.CustomViewPager
                        android:id="@+id/pager"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/tab_layout" />

                </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

                <GridView
                    android:id="@+id/grid_category"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tab_layout"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
                    android:numColumns="2"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:scrollbars="none"
                    android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/float_category"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/categories1"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            app:rippleColor="@android:color/transparent" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#77000000"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:groupIndicator="@null"
        android:listSelector="@color/red_color" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I am facing the problem similar to the Gifs posted in this question:

[Android: CollapsingToolbarLayout and SwipeRefreshLayout get stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30779667/android-collapsingtoolbarlayout-and-swiperefreshlayout-get-stuck)

Comment: please post screenshots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without screenshots/gif it's difficult to understand but I'll try to. 
You need the scroll flag `enterAlways` so that the view will be visible as soon as you start scrolling up.

In the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`:

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAwalys"
```

Also see documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.html