# Scrolling down triggers refresh instead of revealing the toolbar

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout, android-coordinatorlayout

I started using the new CoordinatorLayout and I ran into this issue:

[image: demo]

As you can see when I try to scroll down when the toolbar is partially visible and the recylcerview is at the top position it triggers the refresh event instead of pulling down the toolbar. The user has to scroll up than down again to reveal it.

Layout XML looks something like this:
activity_main.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                style="@style/customActionBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_items" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

fragment_main.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:scrollbars="none" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Ther SwipeRefreshLayout is in a FrameLayout becuase there are more elements in the fragment in my app.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: CollapsingToolbarLayout and SwipeRefreshLayout get stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30779667/android-collapsingtoolbarlayout-and-swiperefreshlayout-get-stuck)

Comment: [This has now been fixed in Support Library v23.1.1 without any workarounds](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33776549/383414)

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier I don't think it's solved entirely. I'm facing the same stuff using 23.3 version.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATE:** This issue has been fixed in the in the Support Library v23.1.1.

Seems like you have to enable/disable the `SwipeRefreshLayout` when the `AppBarLayout` offset changes, using `AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener`.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30822119/795820

Comment: please answer this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434071/android-support-v4-widget-swiperefreshlayout-working-but-it-is-not-visible

Comment: Its back in 23.2.1

Comment: Also for case nested RecyclerView, check here http://stackoverflow.com/a/36895607/1221256

Answer (score 10):

maybe too late but it might help any new comers, i came up with an easy solution for that. by creating custom `class` that extends `SwipeRefreshLayout` you can use it anywhere where `AppBaLayout` exists follow code below

```
    public class MySwipeLayout extends SwipeRefreshLayout implements AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener {
        private AppBarLayout appBarLayout;

        public MySwipeLayout(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public MySwipeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
            super.onAttachedToWindow();
            if (getContext() instanceof Activity) {
                appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) ((Activity) getContext()).findViewById(R.id.appbar);
                appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(this);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
          if(appBarLayout!=null){
            appBarLayout.removeOnOffsetChangedListener(this);
            appBarLayout = null;
          }
          super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        }

        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int i) {
            this.setEnabled(i == 0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nice and clean. Thanks.

Comment: @k0sh please answer this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434071/android-support-v4-widget-swiperefreshlayout-working-but-it-is-not-visible