# How to disable swiperefreshlayout when swiping nested recyclerview's cardview

Tags: android

[image: Img]

When I swipe slightly down on the card in my swiperefreshlayout, it thinks I'm trying to refresh. How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have a nested `RecyclerView`, for example, named `recyclerView` you can call:

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Should stop your `SwipeRefreshLayout` from trying to refresh when you swipe down on a nested RecyclerView's child.
Worked for me with the almighty [Android Support Library 23.2](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.au/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html).
Hope that helps :)

Comment: If that doesn't work you, I'll try and set the trigger distance to a really high value when you start drag like: `mSwipteRefreshLayout.setDistanceToTriggerSync(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
                                mSwipteRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);` and then when you want to set it to to swipe again:             `mSwipteRefreshLayout.setDistanceToTriggerSync((int) (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * 64));
            mSwipteRefreshLayout.setEnabled(true);`

Comment: This answer worked for me. Calling `setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)` prevented child `RecyclerViews` from triggering the parent `RecyclerView`'s `SwipeRefreshLayout`.